# How to access emscripten session data from c++?

Tags: c++, emscripten

I have been banging my head on how to store and retrieve session data for my users with emscripten. I suspect I'm using wrong keywords to search google due to my inexperience.

Anyone has an example handy?

Comment: What is "session data for my users"?

Comment: In my case, it's just key-value pairs I want to persist across runs of the app.

Comment: Still not clear. Do you run your WebAssembly in a browser, in node.js or somewhere else?

Comment: Ah I see. I run it in a browser.

Comment: Have a look at [IDBFS](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#filesystem-api-idbfs). You can find example code in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63966487/11942268) that you already noticed ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't make it save before leaving the session. That's gotta be a problem on my part, so I'll keep digging. Ty!